# Webform Filter Component Roles

Tags: 8, webforms

How may I be able to limit a webform component visibility by logged user role? In Drupal 7, this was possible with [webform_component_roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_component_roles) module but there is no version for Drupal 8.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating/editing a field, scroll down to ELEMENT ACCESS. There you can set all the limitations based on roles.

If you use YML you can use something like:

```
'#access_create_roles':
    - administrator
'#access_update_roles':
    - authenticated
'#access_view_roles':
    - authenticated
```

Finally, if you want to change the accessibility of the webform, check the Access tab (admin/structure/webform/manage/FORM_NAME/access).

Comment: Thank you, that helps but want I wanted to do was to disable a component if the role is not Administrator. Can I do that?

Comment: You can hide it. Or you wan to be visible but not editable? If so you can use hook_form_alter.

Comment: I want it hidden if possible. I have a checkbox that checked disables a textarea element, when I hide the checkbox for the User role the textarea element that was disabled turns enabled and editable... May I use that hook directly on a theme.module file?

Comment: Below the Element Access you will find the CONDITIONAL LOGIC. There, you can set up your conditions based on other fields. The only problem I found here is that you shouldn't require the hidden field as even if it's hidden, on submit, expecting to have a value.

Comment: That's my problem.. I don't know how to solve it. I don't necesseray have to use the button to disable, I just want disabled elements when the user logged role is not administrator. Can I set that through the Elements YAML file? Thank you!

Comment: If you just want hidden fields for certain roles, what you need is the Element Access. You don't need to add extra condition. Just select only the admin role on 'Create webform submission' for the specific field. Using YML : 
    '#access_create_roles':
        - authenticated

Comment: No, I want all the fields to be visible but only editable by administrators... Hiding it's easy but that does not show some users the needed information

Comment: If you want to add condition to a field - YML :  '#states':
        visible:
          ':input[name="YOUR_FIELD"]':
            value: 'No'
        disabled:
          ':input[name="YOUR_FIELD"]':
            value: 'Yes'

Comment: Can't I do something like disabled: ':user_role="Administrator"': true ?

Comment: Then play with the 'access_update_roles' and 'access_view_roles' If you wan to be visible but not editable just select admin in 'access_view_roles'  and none at 'access_update_roles'

Comment: Can't find a way to achieve what I need...,

Comment: Could you give some details? What exactly do you need? You have a webform with some fields and you want it to be editable only by the admin but visible to the other roles. Right? Who is submitting the form? Do you want the data of those fields to be standard for all the users?

Comment: My webform has 3 pages, I want that the first 2 pages may be changed by administrators or creator of the form and the 3th page to be changed by other users and that's why I need to set it disabled when editing. In the third page I want the users to be able to add multiple field collections like date, answer and files. The webform allows me to do mostly anything that I need, except that. Thank you!

Comment: Still I don't get where the problem is. What's the role of the creator? What's the role of the other users? Maybe using hook_form_alter would be an option!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think that I may be thinking wrong. I hiding when updating or creating will do to save my problem. Big help, big thanks!